# How to skip JAR deploy in maven and deploy the assembly only

Tags: maven

My project packages to a Spring Boot fat-jar.

I configured 2 extra build plugins:

- Generate an executable using [Launch4j Plugin](https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin) (it get the resulting fat-jar and embed it on a executable file)
- Assembly the resulting executable in a ZIP

Now I want to deploy **only** the assembly resulting zip to my maven repository.

This is my `build` section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>console</headerType>
                        <outfile>target/${project.build.finalName}.exe</outfile>
                        <jar>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</jar>
                        <manifest>launch4j/besser-updater.manifest</manifest>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher</mainClass>
                        </classPath>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.8.0_131</minVersion>
                            <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                            <runtimeBits>32/64</runtimeBits>
                        </jre>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>launch4j/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I configure the deploy phase to ignore the **jar** artifact and deploy only the **zip** assembly file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. I just ignored the `default-deploy` execution id.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <!-- disable standard deploy -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: did not work for me.
Repository "comgithubriprasad-1048" failures
[ERROR]   Rule "javadoc-staging" failures
[ERROR]     * Missing: no main jar artifact found in folder '/com/github/riprasad/service-registry-ocp-install-examples/1.0.1'
[ERROR]   Rule "sources-staging" failures
[ERROR]     * Missing: no main jar artifact found in folder '/com/github/riprasad/service-registry-ocp-install-examples/1.0.1'

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the assembly to deploy or are you talking about simply avoiding the install of the dependencies in your remote repo?

If you are talking about the assembly plugin you can easily exclude jars with it

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html

You can avoid to deploy the single artifact like this:

```
<build>
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
       <skip>true</skip>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
...
</build>
```

Then you can specify the specific file to deploy just including into the deploy plugin configuration.

reference: http://prystash.blogspot.ie/2009/06/maven-excluding-module-from-deploy.html

Hope it helps..

Comment: I want just call `mvn deploy` and the result I expect in the remote repository is only see the **zip** artifact and no **jar**. Now if I perform the deploy It uploads the jar and the zip.

Comment: This will skip the whole deploy, I don't want do skip the entire deploy, only the deploy of classifier **jar**.